# Prove Inequality Is True By Induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

$3^n  ≥  n^3 +1$  for the integer $n ≥ 4$.
I let $n=0$ and the inequality is turns into $1 ≥ 1$ which is true.
Then I let $n=n+1$ and the inequality turns into $3^{n+1}  ≥ (n+1)^3 +1$.
Now from here I get stuck. I tried to expand the right side and I got $3^{n+1} ≥ n^3+3n^2+3n+2$ but still was confused as to how to carry on the next steps from here.

Comment: The stated result fails for $n=3$.

Comment: The base case is not $n=0$, but $n=4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $3^n\geq n^3+1$ and $n\geq 4$, then:
$$ 3^{n+1} = 3\cdot 3^n \geq 3\cdot(n^3+1) \geq (n+1)^3+1 $$
because the last inequality is equivalent to:
$$ 2n^3 -3n^2 -3n + 1 = n^2(n-3)+n(n^2-3)+1\geq 0 $$
that is trivial.